# How to pass the appState (provider) into a screen in initState?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have this issue

> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_DefaultInheritedProviderScope>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _NavigationBarState.initState() completed.

And what I was trying to pass a value of the `AppState` to a screen and both are in `initState`.

The `initState`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: true);
  screens = [
    Home(),
    Search(),
    AddPost(),
    Notifications(),
    Profile(appState.currentUser),
 ];
  super.initState();
}
```

And my `AppState`:

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  AppState() {
    _fetchAll();
  }
// User
  var currentUser = CurrentUser();
  var lastUser = LastUser();

  Future<void> _fetchCurrentUser() async {
    currentUser.fetchUser('0');
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAll() async {
    print('fetching');
    _fetchCurrentUser();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

How it should be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `listen: true` inside `initState`. Use `listen: false` instead:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Provider.of<Whatever>(context, listen: false);
}
```